# Angular nested routes vs pages

Tags: angular, angular-ui-router

I have a typical resource oriented REST API for buildings:

/buildings/

/buildings/:buildingId

/buildings/:buildingId/floors

/buildings/:buildingId/floors/:floorId

And I am writing an angular 8 application oriented to this which should use ths same routing.

Firstly I tried nested routes:

```
  {
    path: 'buildings',
    component: BuildingsComponent,
    children: [
      {
        path: ':id',
        component: BuildingComponent,
        children: [
          {
            path: 'floors',
            component: FloorsComponent,
            children: [
              {
                path: ':id',
                component: FloorComponent
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
```

But this seems to only support hierarchies of components. This for me means thatI have to keep the output of each parent component on screen, which on the lowest level would look something like:

```
[building list table]
[selected building data]
[floor list table]
[selected floor data]
```

But I want to have independent pages:

```
[building list table]
```

select building ->

```
[selected building data]
[floor list table]
```

select floor ->

```
[selected floor data]
```

For this I used a flattened router config:

```
  {
    path: 'buildings',
    component: BuildingsComponent,
  },
  {
    path: 'buildings/:buildingId',
    component: BuildingComponent,
  },
  {
    path: 'buildings/:buildingId/floors/:floorId',
    component: FloorComponent,
  }
```

But what I am missing here is that each component in the hierarchy was fetching it's data from the REST API.

Is there a mechanism for such a scenario that I can use instead of having to have all rest calls at each level (i.e. for the level you are at and all parent levels)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're looking for is a [resolver](https://angular.io/api/router/Resolve). A resolver makes API calls on a route level. The data from the REST API will be available through your router.

If you're looking to reduce the amount of API calls your application makes, consider [caching using interceptors](https://blog.fullstacktraining.com/caching-http-requests-with-angular/), using [graphQL](https://graphql.org/) for queries, or [NgRx](https://ngrx.io/) to better manage your state.

Comment: That was the solution for my flat routes case. Thanks. I was also wondering if people oftern go the nested routes way and use styling / conditional elements to control the display of the nested components to such an extent that it feels like a subpage.

Comment: Depends on the use case, imagine you're setting up a client and admin portal on the same route. Instead of managing separate projects,  it would make sense to treat deeper-routes ( e.g. `admin/dashboard` ) as subpages, as you might wish to inherit a portal-specific header and footer.

Flat routes structure are for separate pages, such as `products/:id` and `contact-us`.